# Why does ArrayList.subList(0, n) return a List of size n?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, sublist

I would have thought this question would have been answered before, but can't seem to find anything about it.

My question is as the title says, why does creating a sublist from index to index, not return the total number of indexes I'd expect?

A more detailed example:

```
List slice = points.sublist(20, 48);
Log.i(TAG, slice.size());
```

I would expect the log to return 29 in the example above, but in actual fact it returns 28.

Why does this happen and what is the correct solution to this? To add +1 to the second index, or -1 to the first index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clearly written in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) that sublist:

> public List subList(int fromIndex,
>                 int toIndex)
>
> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.

To answer your question, as far as I understand, you might want to add `+1` to the second parameter, because it is not included in the sublist.

Comment: It would appear I was being dumb then. I checked the documentation numerous times and missed the word 'exclusive' it seems... Thanks.

Comment: @nineteeneightyeight If you had checked the documentation, I'd recommend putting that in the question as research you've done.  First, when writing out your research, you're more likely to have seen this note in the documentation.  Second, if it comes off like you did research before posting your question, it is less likely to be downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Doc:

> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
>   Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, **inclusive**, and toIndex, **exclusive**.

General use case for what you are asking for is:

```
points.sublist(20, points.size());
```

Answer (score 1):

The first index is inclusive, the other is exclusive.
a.subList(0,n) returns a list containing elements 0,1,2,...,n-1

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-)

Answer (score 1):

> *I would expect the log to return 29 in the example above*

Not really, according to the [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

**subList**(int fromIndex,
               int toIndex)

> Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified
>   fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.  (If
>   fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list 
>   is  empty.)  The returned list is backed by this list, so 
>   non-structural  changes in the returned list are reflected in this 
>   list, and vice-versa.  The returned list supports all of the optional 
>   list operations supported  by this list

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `subList` :

```
/**
 * Returns a {@code List} of the specified portion of this {@code List} from the given start
 * index to the end index minus one. The returned {@code List} is backed by this
 * {@code List} so changes to it are reflected by the other.
 *
 * @param start
 *            the index at which to start the sublist.
 * @param end
 *            the index one past the end of the sublist.
 * @return a list of a portion of this {@code List}.
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException
 *                if {@code start < 0, start > end} or {@code end >
 *                size()}
 */
public List<E> subList(int start, int end);
```

As you can see, the `end` param is "the index one past the one of the sublist".
Therefore when you say "stop at 48", it actually copies the item 47 and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the javadoc pretty clear on this point, the extracted sublist is including the fromIndex and excluding the toIndex in List.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)

Therefore subList(0,1) will return a List of one element only : the first one.

[Sublist javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))